# How to get the length of a JSON object, that represents data from a database table?

Tags: javascript, json

I have converted a database table into a JSON object.

This is in essence a two-dimensional array, with each record being the first dimension, which is an enumerated array, and the second dimension of fields, an associative array.

```
Object
1: {act_id: "3", name: "Bruce Waelbrock Music Scholarship", category: "Life", KIC: "Chester Patch III", description: ""}
2: {act_id: "4", name: "Christmas Childrens Gift Drive", category: "Community", KIC: "John Evalle", description: ""}
3: {act_id: "5", name: "Church Drive", category: "Faith", KIC: "", description: ""}
4: {act_id: "6", name: "Church Kiosk", category: "Faith", KIC: "Diego Rivera", description: ""}
5: {act_id: "7", name: "Consecration of the Holy Family", category: "Family", KIC: "Roger Olaes", description: ""}
```

The number of the enumerated records, in the above example, 1 - 5, so that the number is this example would be '5'.

I've tried something like console.log(act_obj_array.length); , but the console only displays undefined.

Comment: Try Object.keys(act_obj_array).length. Reason: the result seems to be an object if I'm interpreting the pasted sample correctly, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the list of keys in the Object as an array and then get the length from it:

```
Object.keys(act_obj_array).length;
```

Comment: Harshana.  You're a genius!  I saw similar code examples before, but the example wasn't as straight forward.  And, I thought that, instead of the keyword 'Object', I substituted the variable that represented my object, in this case 'act_obj_array'.  Your answer was so concise and clear, as, I hope, my question was as well.